# Trouble configuring OpenVPN connection from Mullvad

Tags: network-manager, openvpn

I am using this guide:

https://www.mullvad.net/guides/linux-openvpn-installation/

to set up an `openvpn` connection using the network manager.

The problem I'm running into (I think) is instruction #14, which asks me to

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` and change `dns=dnsmasq` to       `#dns=dnsmasq` and save.

I am at a loss as to how to perform this task. I tried opening the file `NetworkManager.conf` that I found in the folder/subfolders `/etc/NetworkManager` and editing the text, but couldn't save it as it was a read only document and I didn't have permission. I also didn't have permission to save it as something else.

I've set everything else up, and configured the connection through the Network Manager, imported certs etc. I can get it to connect, but it won't find the internet. I don't know if it's directly related to the issue I've described, but that seems the most logical place to start. I really appreciate any help you can give me. I'm new to privacy protection and am trying to piece things together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running into a very common problem. You have forgot to use `sudo`.

So instead of:

```
vim /etc/NetworkManager.conf
```

do:

```
sudo vim /etc/NetworkManager.conf
```

Replace `vim` with `nano` or whatever editor you use.

Comment: you have to run those in the terminal obviously ;)

Comment: I am such a beginner that I didn't know how run those in the terminal, so I researched text editors and was able to open the file but was a little overwhelmed by the format of vim. Then I bumped into a discussion on sed commands and was able to use that to change the necessary text through the terminal. Viola it works!!!! Thank you thank you for pointing me in the right direction and so politely too!

Comment: Realized this morning that the command line I used might be helpful  to someone else. It was: sudo sed -i 's/dns=dnsmasq/#dns=dnsmasq/g' 
 /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf